# Laravel 5.7 Login Form Route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I made a fresh install of Laravel 5.7, and I'm trying to change the view it renders when I go to `/login`.

When I list my routes, it says that the route /login uses logic from 'LoginController@showLoginForm', but I can't see it in the **controller**:

> php artisan route:list
>   [image]

and when I go to the `LoginController`, this showLoginForm method doesn't seem to exist...

> LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Where is the boilerplate that I can change for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "use AuthenticatesUsers" it extends functionality and also brings the showLoginForm to the controller.

If you want to add code to that function you just need to overwrite it.

If youre using an IDE like PHPStorm you can control click through the "use" declaration to see whats being imported, or you can go manually look inside Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this but my code editor (Atom) didn't index my vendor file. I was wondering where these classes were...

Comment: @Vranvs You can always check the imports to see where stuff is getting imported from for future reference. PS. If this answered your question, please mark it as so :)

Answer (score 1):

`showLoginForm()` exists on trait `AuthenticatesUsers`

Just try override `showLoginForm()` method :)

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function showLoginForm() {
    // Your code
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm using Auth::routes() in my web.php file. I don't like making it messy like that. I'd rather just do it properly haha

Comment: @Vranvs Thats the proper way of doing it... You cant go and modify core files itll cause youre more trouble than its worth

Comment: I mean override it in your controller

Answer (score 1):

it is in :

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

find it and override in loginController

this is that code on vendor:

```
   public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
```

Comment: What is the path to this file? My code editor cant find it when I search

Comment: move your mouse on AuthenticatesUsers and click on it, it will go to AuthenticatesUsers.php file

Answer (score 1):

Login form view is located in `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`
You can easily change it